# Remove a sub property from a class

Tags: c#

Is there a way to remove a sub property from a class nested in a class object? What i need to achieve is the alteration of a coplex nested class structure to remove unwanted properties from the entire object before serialisation, is this possible?

I've tried an ExpandoObject but with this converted to a dictionary i only seem to be able to remove the 'top-level' properties.

Here's and basic example of the structure where i would want to remove the property named 'OneOneOneOne' before serialisation:

```
Class One
{
   new Class OneOne
   {
      new Class OneOneOne
      {
         int OneOneOneOne
      }
      string OneOneTwo 
   }
   new Class OneTwo
   {
       int OneTwoOne
   }
   int OneThree
}
```

A solution with 'ignore' tags for serialisation might not work as i need to have various serialisation structures based off the original object and data.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  A simple, concrete example would go a long way.

Comment: Depending on the serializer you might be able to tell it to ignore certain ones.  It may also depend on what you mean by `sub property'

Comment: Edited the question with an example, basically i have a fully initialised object but need to send it to multiple customers who each want a certain version of the object with certain properties removed. I would rather not create various classes but instead use the one with all data then 'trim' it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serializing to Json then you can just add the following attribute to the property in question

```
[JsonIgnore]
```

There is `[XmlIgnore]` too.

If you need more flexibility in manipulating the data then why not create a DTO (data transfer object), map into that as you wish and return this object.

Automapper works very well with these scenarios and saves you having to do lots of manual plumbing.  It can give clarity of the mapping too.